# OSGI javax.ws.rs maven install failed

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, tycho, equinox

I'm developing a plugin for the OM2M project which is based on equinox.
When I run maven install I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: parent ......................... SUCCESS [  0.155 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: commons ........................ SUCCESS [  1.031 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: logging fragment ............... SUCCESS [  0.088 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: binding service ................ SUCCESS [  0.069 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: core service ................... SUCCESS [  0.060 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: binding http ................... SUCCESS [  0.091 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: binding coap ................... SUCCESS [  0.101 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: data mapping service ........... SUCCESS [  0.063 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: persistence service ............ SUCCESS [  0.077 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: persistence eclipselink ........ SUCCESS [  1.483 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: datamapper jaxb ................ SUCCESS [  0.099 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: webapp resourcesbrowser xml .... SUCCESS [  0.137 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: webapp resourcesbrowser json ... SUCCESS [  0.135 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: interworking service ........... SUCCESS [  0.057 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: core ........................... SUCCESS [  0.225 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: ipe sample ..................... SUCCESS [  0.187 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: asn product .................... SUCCESS [  5.274 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: webservice ..................... SUCCESS [  0.462 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: in product ..................... FAILURE [  0.213 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m :: mn product ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.eclipse.om2m.rest_webservice ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 26.251 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-18T20:49:47+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 102M/584M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.20.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse: Exception while publishing product om2m/org.eclipse.om2m/org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse/om2m.product: publishing result: [Included element org.eclipse.om2m.rest_webservice 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.] -> [Help 1]
```

I'm new to OSGI and plugin development. And I am also new to Maven and tycho. So I am a little bit lost and a little bit help would be really appreciated
Thanks !

Here are the results with maven clean install -X:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.20.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse: Exception while publishing product om2m/org.eclipse.om2m/org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse/om2m.product: publishing result: [Included element org.eclipse.om2m.rest_webservice 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.20.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse: Exception while publishing product om2m/org.eclipse.om2m/org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse/om2m.product
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception while publishing product om2m/org.eclipse.om2m/org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse/om2m.product
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.publisher.PublishProductMojo.publishContent(PublishProductMojo.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.publisher.AbstractPublishMojo.execute(AbstractPublishMojo.java:36)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.FacadeException: publishing result: [Included element org.eclipse.om2m.rest_webservice 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.publisher.PublisherServiceImpl.handlePublisherStatus(PublisherServiceImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.publisher.PublisherServiceImpl.executePublisher(PublisherServiceImpl.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.publisher.PublisherServiceImpl.publishProduct(PublisherServiceImpl.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.publisher.PublishProductMojo.publishContent(PublishProductMojo.java:100)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: try `mvn clean install - X` for more detailed logs

Comment: I already tried it but it didn't help a lot.

Comment: It looks like an ordering problem. It's trying to find `org.eclipse.om2m.rest_webservice`, which is later in the build order.

Comment: I did some research, everything works fine until I add `<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0-m10</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>`  to om2m.rest_webservice pom file. Do you know why these dependency change the build orfer?